# Javascript, trying to add a line brake within a while loop

Tags: javascript, loops, if-statement, while-loop

Need to create a chessboard with the following rule set:

Write a program that creates a string that represents an 8×8 grid, using newline characters to separate lines. At each position of the grid there is either a space or a "#" character. The characters should form a chessboard.

Passing this string to console.log should show something like this:

```
 # # # #
# # # # 
 # # # #
# # # # 
 # # # #
# # # # 
 # # # #
# # # #
```

Here is the code i wrote for it:

```
    var chessBoardSize = 8;
        var chessBoard = " ";
        var lineBreakCount = 0;

        while (chessBoard.length <= chessBoardSize * chessBoardSize) {

            lineBreakCount++;

            if (lineBreakCount === chessBoardSize) {
                chessBoard += "\n";
                lineBreakCount = 0;
            }

            if (chessBoard.slice(-1) === " ") {
                chessBoard = chessBoard + "#";
            } else if (chessBoard.slice(-1) === "#") {
                chessBoard = chessBoard + " ";
            }

        }

        console.log(chessBoard);
```

I'm having trouble to get the string on a new line once 8 characters have been used on that line. This is the part of the program i'm trying to figure out:

```
lineBreakCount++;

        if (lineBreakCount === chessBoardSize) {
            chessBoard += "\n";
            lineBreakCount = 0;
        }
```

When i run the code, i get back this:

```
 # # # #
```

But, it should be this:

```
 # # # #
# # # # 
 # # # #
# # # # 
 # # # #
# # # # 
 # # # #
# # # #
```

Comment: You're adding a newline character to the end of the string, but then the next lines of code never check for it. They only check for space and `#`. So the check for a space should also include a check for the newline. Not sure if that makes your code correct, but is a missing component.

Comment: It seems like what you should really do is just alternate whether you append `"# "` vs `" #"` based on whether you're on an odd or even iteration and row.

Comment: When you do `chessBoard += "\n"`, what happens is `chessBoard.slice(-1)` becomes `\n`. So when you check for `"#"` or `" "` you're appending nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your logic doesn't handle the fact that the last character maybe a newline character not just '#' or ' '.
This should work:

```js
var chessBoardSize = 8;
var chessBoard = " ";
var lineBreakCount = 0;
var max = chessBoardSize*chessBoardSize;
for(let i = 1; i < max; i++) {

  lineBreakCount++;

  if (lineBreakCount === chessBoardSize) {
    chessBoard += "\n";
    lineBreakCount = 0;
  }

  if (chessBoard[chessBoard.length - 1] === '\n') {
    chessBoard += chessBoard[chessBoard.length - 2];
  } else if(chessBoard.slice(-1) === " ") {
    chessBoard += '#';
  } else {
    chessBoard = chessBoard + " ";
  }

}

console.log(chessBoard);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to solve a **simple problem** with **complex solution**.

The result is a **Matrix** which means you ( maybe not required ) need nested loops.

1. Loop through columns.
2. Loop through a line.
3. Add checks `if-else` to choose between `#`or `" "`.

We see the position of `#` is only on a case that achieves this math rule: `case%2 === 0`.

```js
 

const chessboard = (size, lineLength) => {

    for (let vindex = 0; vindex < size + 1; vindex++) {
        let line = String("");
        for (let hindex = 0; hindex < lineLength + 1; hindex++) {
            vindex % 2 === 0 && ((hindex % 2 === 0 && (line += "#")) || (line += " "))
            vindex % 2 != 0 && ((hindex % 2 != 0 && (line += "#")) || (line += " "))
        }
        console.log(line)

    }
}
chessboard(8, 10)
```